# how to set slideToggle to work for more than one time

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have some nested ul tags and I hide them so that I can apply jQuery slideToggle effect to them( I want to slide each element independently). but when I press each 'li' tag in the first 'ul' all the second 'ul's become visible together.

This how my html code is:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="mainList">
          <li class="mainItem">List item</li>
                     <ul class="subList">
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li> 
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                     </ul>
          <li class="mainItem">>List item</li>
                     <ul class="subList">
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li> 
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                     </ul>
          <li class="mainItem">>List item</li>
                     <ul class="subList">
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li> 
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                     </ul> 
          <li class="mainItem">>List item</li>
                     <ul class="subList">
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li> 
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                     </ul>
          <li class="mainItem">>List item</li>
                     <ul class="subList">
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li> 
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                         <li class="subItem">List item</li>
                     </ul>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And the js file looks like this:

```
$('.content').click(function(){
   $('.mainList').slideToggle();
});
$('.mainItem').click(function(){
   $('.subList').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but
here is a fiddle that might help you: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqLJy/)

Some notes:

In your jquery: you have an error functin -> function.

If you want to affect only one element you should use unique IDs or Use

```
$(this)...
```

**this** will indicate using only the element who triggered the event (in your example "click")
and now u can use *next()*, *prev()*, *children()*, *parent()*, *find()*, etc - to select another relative element .

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrs4c/

Corrected your markup and script typo's and created the correct jquery.

```
$('.mainItem').next().children().slideToggle();

$('.mainItem').click(function(){
    $(this).next().children().slideToggle();
});
```